# Response must contain an array or object at "feed.entry". amp-list

Tags: amp-html, amp-list

I am getting this error while making amp list with CORS proxy
my code

```
<amp-list items='feed.entry' layout="fixed-height" height="100" src="https://cdn.nixs.in/cdn/cors/?url=https://www.nixs.in/feeds/posts/default?alt=json" binding="no"> <template type="amp-mustache"> <div>{{#title}}{{$t}}{{/title}}</div> </template> </amp-list>
```

its returns **Response must contain an array or object at "feed.entry". amp-list**
but my array object in the feed.entry location

I found few links where some solution given but no one work for me

[how to remove this error "Response must contain an array at " . "." while making dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49020895/how-to-remove-this-error-response-must-contain-an-array-at-while-making)

https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/10613
https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/9687

here is my code https://jsbin.com/yoruvalego/edit?html,js,output

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does your JSON have the hierarchy: items/feed/entry? i don't see it.

Comment: no @Jay Gray my json have "feed/entry" as mentioned in "https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DV61.png"

Comment: so why do you expect the hop operator `feed.entry` to work if those keys are not in the JSON? Just use `single-item` and bracket the item as you do in your `<template>`.